# Would someone looking for this question know what a "codomain" is?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions, search, titles

Looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4200272/167197) should the word "codomain" be changed to "range" in the title to make this post more easily find-able by those with same question? I.e. do kids these days even use the word "codomain"? It's not *quite* correct to talk about the range in that question because that's not what I'm thinking of, but I'm worried students who also have this question and search for it won't find this post because they only know the word range.

Some clarification based on the comments: the range of a function is it's image, and the range is a subset of the codomain.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127734/discussion-on-question-by-mike-pierce-would-someone-looking-for-this-question-kn).

Comment: Can we aim to formulate an answer?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff No. :) At least that's the impression I was getting from the comments here. There is no good way to definitively answer this question.

Comment: I think one can take into consideration the vocabulary of a target "audience" for a Question and tweak its wording accordingly.  In most cases the person who posts a Question will tend to use (or misuse) terms with which they are familiar.  So most of the time we ought to respect the wording (and notation) that the OP favors.  In this case it was your Question, and likely you are concerned not about your own preference but that of a wider audience (which is where the matter becomes "vexed").

Comment: @hardmath It's like 100% likely that I'm concerned not about my own preference but that of a wider audience ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've edited the question in question to have the words "*codomain*" and "*range*".

Based on the [comments here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127734/discussion-on-question-by-mike-pierce-would-someone-looking-for-this-question-kn), there is no good way to definitively answer this question. Some say that "*codomain*" is a word only introduced in the context of category theory, whereas some have seen it sneak into the vocabulary of earlier curriculum. Personally I'd only seen it in my first course on set theory, but I'd seen "*codomain*" later assistant-teaching a precalculus class, but wasn't sure if it was a quirk of the instructor or the new normal thing to do. So I guess site users who have this same question might use either word *"codomain"* or "*range*" to describe their question, so I've included them both.